# How would "Sinophile" be translated into Mandarin Chinese?

Tags: translation, mandarin

The word isn't in my physical dictionary, and online I can only find "親華派", "親中家", and "中國迷". Are any of these accurate translations? What would they all accurately translate to?

Answer (score 4):

Native Chinese from Shanghai.

If *Sinophile* is used to describe a politician, 亲华派 or 亲中派 (there is no difference between these two words) would probably be the most accurate translation and in fact still used in both spoken Mandarin and newspaper. It's a neutral word to describe someone's political stance.

In some specific context, if *Sinophile* is used to describe someone not only favors Chinese culture, but in fact has *deep* understanding in Chinese culture, 中国通 would be an excellent alternative. Note that it would infer that person has sort of academic background or works for a foreign(not Chinese) government.

However if it is used to describe someone who favors Chinese culture, for example, a folk collects china or has a taste for Chinese ancient literature, you can use 中国迷. Note that it is not used as frequently as the aforementioned words, and *sometimes* people would put double quotation mark on it since it is not a solid word in dictionary. 他是一个不折不扣的"中国迷". (He is a real sinophile.)

Comment: I am not talking about how the terms are used in China, I do not know much about that. 
 But for translating published material from English I would reserve 中国通 for "China hand,"  these are famous terms in English.  See https://baike.sogou.com/v7665312.htm

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Good comment

Answer (score 2):

> sino-
> before vowels Sin-, word-forming element meaning "Chinese,"
> 1879, from Late Latin Sinæ (plural) "the Chinese," from Ptolemaic
> Greek Sinai, from Arabic Sin "China," probably from Chinese Ch'in,
> name of the fourth dynasty of China

and

> -phile
> from philos "loving, friendly, dear; related, own," related to philein
> "to love,"

adj. 亲华的；
adj. 爱好中国的
n. 喜爱中国者